# Modify package names of generated java classes for wsdl and xsd in gradle application

Tags: gradle, jaxb, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I am working on an app using `Gradle kotlin dsl`, ie **build.gradle** is in Kotlin. I have a WSDL file that imports multiple XSDs. while compiling, Java classes are getting generated in the default location(which is mentioned in the XSDs). My requirement is that Java classes of each XSD should be generated in the **custom location**.

I am referring an another maven project for this. The following plugin is used to achieve my requirement.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources-sample</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl_file_name.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>urn:namespace:of:xsd:one=com.first.xsd.from.wsdl</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>urn:namespace:of:xsd:one=com.second.xsd.from.wsdl</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have tried using wsdl2Java task to assign a custom location. I could not use the task as it needs CXF. It may lead to jar conflicts in my application.

```
extra["cxfVersion"] = "3.1.5"
project.wsdl2javaExt {
cxfVersion = "${property("cxfVersion")}"
}

tasks.getByName<no.nils.wsdl2java.Wsdl2JavaTask>("wsdl2java") {
wsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/xsd/trip") // wslds location
generatedWsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/generated-sources/xjc/newpackage") // store generates java classes to
wsdlsToGenerate = arrayListOf(
        arrayListOf("$wsdlDir/wsdl_file_name.wsdl"),
        arrayListOf("-xjc", "-autoNameResolution",
                "$wsdlDir/wsdl_file_name.wsdl")
        )
}
```

Please guide me to get the same behavior in Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it by adding the custom location in binding.xjb file in my application. The following changes worked for me.

```
    <jaxb:bindings xmlns:tns="urn:namespace:of:xsd:one" scd="x-schema::tns">
            <jaxb:schemaBindings>
                <jaxb:package name="com.first.xsd.from.wsdl"/>
            </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:tns="urn:namespace:of:xsd:two" scd="x-schema::tns">
            <jaxb:schemaBindings>
                <jaxb:package name="com.second.xsd.from.wsdl"/>
            </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```